# Microsoft Graph API for confluence site search

Tags: search, microsoft-graph-api, confluence

I am working on a requirement where I need to use Microsoft Graph API for confluence site search. I know graph API can be used for share point search. But is there any way we can do confluence site search??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Confluence type you use:

- For the Server version, you can create custom add-n that uses Java API https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/javadoc/7.17.0/ or you can use REST API https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-server-rest-api/ to i9ntegrate Microsopht Grap API and this API.
- For Cloud Confluence version you can just use REST API https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/intro/ directly or use Forge or Spring Boot/JS based add-oons and REST API